Power Apps Table control - Hide and show attachment image
I'm using a table control in power apps.
There is an Attachments and a Has Attachment field (This is the Files column below).
By default the Has Attachment displays the yes and no as in the screenshot.
What I'm after is I would like to use the Attachment field showing the pin to hide and show the attachments (When there is an attachment or not).
How to control fields when using Table control. It should be easy but I'm missing something.


Hi Ganesh, Is this currently possible with the table control?
